# Google chrome extension to get dynamic generated code link address?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, web-development

As a developer I work a lot with WordPress and ASP.net websites ( dynamic generated content from database ), Are there any plug-ins able to track the source of the generated code and let me know the section or the page that code come from?

Comment: are you talking about pressing F12? [Example](http://puu.sh/6UfVi.png)

Comment: NO, i use the DevTools in all my work but you can't know the source of dynamic generated contents.